# Is it possible to use the same adobe edge animation in the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, adobe-edge

I am new to adobe edge and want to know if it is possible to use the same animation more than once in the same page?

What I mean here is I have parent div elements that hold each animation and I put a display:none style on each div page that I want to hide and then remove it when I want to show the animation.

So I have the following:

```
<div>
  <!-- Adobe Edge animation --->
</div>
<div style="display:none">
  <!-- Adobe Edge animation (same as above)--->
</div>
```

I alternate between the two divs setting the style and removing it. Since my animations are the same the reason I am doing this is I am using angularjs to inject in my data so that each animation plays with different data.

What I am seeing is the last animation is shown and runs but only the CSS is shown for the first animation as it does not play.

I think this is because JQuery is used to target specific elements and as we now have duplicates (same animation), the last animation is played.

Is there a way I can overcome this?

Can I modify the edge scripts generated to target only the elements which do not have the parent div without a class 'style:none'?

Thanks

Comment: Where is your jQuery code?

Comment: It is all generated from Adobe Edge, all I do is use is use ng-hide from angularjs that sets the class style to none. I need confirmation is this is the issue and if I can overcome it.

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery to clone the `div` instead of Adobe Edge making two of them (never used it).  Would give you more control?